# Difference between ActiveRecord and ActiveRecord::Relation objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord, active-relation

I have searched but not able to find the brief explanation for the difference between ActiveRecord and ActiveRecord::relation object.

I have understand that ActiveRecord is the single object find by something like

```
User.find(1)
```

And ActiveRecord::Relation is the array like object Find by something like

```
User.where(id: 1)
```

I am looking for the difference between them in terms of query execution or deep explanation about them, so it will clear the whole concept behind it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

An instance of `ActiveRecord::Base` is an object that represents a specific row of your database (or might be saved into the database).

Whereas, an instance of `ActiveRecord::Relation` is a representation of a query that can be run against your database (but wasn't run yet). Once you run that query by calling `to_a`, `each`, `first` etc. on that `Relation` a single instance or an array of `ActiveRecord::Base` instances will be returned.

Comment: thanks @spickermann, when I try on rails console then it shows me sql query is get executed in case of active record relation, but it should not be because it is a representation. Can you please explain about it?

Comment: @power : It gets executed in the console, because the console calls `inspect` on that relation to output the result. If you change the line to not return the relation (like `User.where(id: 10); nil`), you will see that the query is not run. Whereas `User.find(10); nil` would still run the query.

Comment: Is it too simplistic to say: `ActiveRecord::Base` represents a row from the database, and `ActiveRecord::Relation` represent an sql query that will query a database? So this is the fundamental difference between FinderMethods and QueryMethods, perhaps?

Answer (score 5):

Rails uses activerecord as standard ORM but the same applies for activerecord on its own.

In short: all queries that yield multiple records like scopes, all, where, and joins return an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object. You can **chain** these together, and it is only when you use a method like to_sql, first, each, any, to_a, take, last etc that the query is executed and returns an array of `ActiveRecord::Base` instead

---

- All this is explained on the [following site](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html)

  - Especially the section on [scopes](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes), [query methods](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#retrieving-objects-from-the-database) and the examples for [`pluck`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#pluck) show all the details on the main differences
- See also
  [the rails API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html) for reference

Answer (score 2):

when you use record by find method and that record not present in the database than you will get below error

```
User.find(10)


User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 10]] ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find User with 'id'=10
```

and if you find user by where condition and if user not present in database than you will get nill record like below

```
User.where(id: 10)


User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  [["id", 10]]
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>
```

It will not give any error